# Missing thumbnails

Tags: post-thumbnails

For all the pics I upload to Wordpress I get such a link to the pic:

```
src='http://myblog.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/thumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/2012/06/mypic.jpg&w=100&h=100&zc=1&q=90'
```

Anf ofcourse Wordpress does not find it.

But if I change to with the firebug:

```
src='http://myblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/mypic.jpg'
```

Wordpress displays the picture. Where I should look for the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you use a WordPress theme which uses some kind of php library to resize images. You should really use WordPress default `add_image_size()` and `wp_get_attachment_image` but if you were the one who created the theme you would already know that.

There are 3 things you can do:

- find a new theme that is not **that** outdated
- dive into `mytheme/thumb.php` and find out whats going on and where it fails
- update the theme wherever it uses thumbnails and/or different image sizes with the above default WP functions